# How do I get tags to pull through from New Relic's Redis integration to New Relic?

Tags: redis, newrelic

I have a Redis server which I've just installed the New Relic infrastructure agent on. The data about the instance is reporting to New Relic however the tag I included is missing on the website.

I have this in the config which should pull through as a tag as per the documentation however it's not visible on the website:

```
labels:
      environment: staging
```

Answer (score 0):

yaml can be finnicky with spacing - maybe try with only 2 spaces under the `labels` stanza like this?

```
labels:
  environment: staging
```

You could also check the infrastructure agent logs to see if there are some parsing errors.

Comment: Reference sample config file: https://github.com/newrelic/nri-redis/blob/master/redis-config.yml.sample

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, I've also tried tag, tags and label in case they updated the syntax and not the documentation.
I've never programmed with go but I did a quick scan of the repo and the word 'labels' does not occur in any of the code files which does seem suspicious, like the NR integration spec requires them but they didn't get round to writing the actual code.

Comment: Hmm weird - maybe open a GH issue on that repo?